# How to fetch data 10 days back from table according to today date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, days

I have form where is search box.I want after entering  today date in this search-box and clicking on submit button I  get 10 days back records from database. I have following columns in table (name of table=issuedevices).
Device_ID,Employee_id,Employee_Name,Employee_Ext,Issue_Date

When I am using following query and entering the date that is in column issue_date getting record of that date .
 pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "');

When I am writing query like following nothing is happening
pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "'- INTERVAL '10' DAY");

```
try 
          {
                   String str = tf5.getText();
                   Connection con=DB.getConnection();
                   PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date=?");
                 //  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM issuedevices WHERE Issue_Date > sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY;");

                   st.setString(1, str);
                   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

             //       Vector v = new Vector();
               if (rs.next()) 
                    {
                         frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
                         frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                         frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                        //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
                         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                         model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
                         table = new JTable();
                         table.setModel(model);
                         table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
                         table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                           JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
                           scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                                   JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                           scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                                   JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                 //  from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();
                             String id = "";
                             String Device_ID = "";
                             String Employee_id = "";
                             String Employee_Name = "";
                             String Employee_Ext = "";
                             String Issue_Date= "";

                try {
                      //  pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date='" + str + "'");
                       pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date BETWEEN '" + str + "' - INTERVAL '11' DAY  AND '" + str + "'");
                       // pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "'- INTERVAL '10' DAY");

                        ResultSet rs1 = pst.executeQuery();

                        int i = 0;
                        if (rs1.next())
                        {
                            id = rs1.getString("id");
                            Device_ID = rs1.getString("Device_ID");
                            Employee_id = rs1.getString("Employee_id");
                            Employee_Name = rs1.getString("Employee_Name");
                            Employee_Ext=rs1.getString("Employee_Ext");
                            Issue_Date=rs1.getString("Issue_Date");

                            model.addRow(new Object[]{id, Device_ID, Employee_id,Employee_Name,Employee_Ext,Issue_Date});
                            i++;
                        }
                        if (i < 1) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        if (i == 1) 
                        {
                            System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
                        }
                } 
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        frame1.add(scroll);
                        frame1.setVisible(true);
                        frame1.setSize(400, 300);
                    }

                    st.close();
                    rs.close();
          } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name not Found");
          }
```

Comment: `pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "');` -> that's not how prepared statements work ... please read again about it. Same for `pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date BETWEEN '" + str + "' - INTERVAL '11' DAY  AND '" + str +`

Comment: regarding the empty result, are you sure the date is in the right format?

Comment: 2019-06-03 is format in table displaying

Comment: But when I am using

Comment: Like I have date 2019-05-28 in my database column name "Issue_Date".When I am searching with this date records are displaying .pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "'); How I get 10 days back records

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

```
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date BETWEEN ? AND ?;");
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Isle_of_Man"));
    pst.setObject(1, today.minusDays(10));
    pst.setObject(2, today);
```

Don’t hand build your query string. Use parameters. And don’t pass date parameters as strings, but as `LocalDate` objects. As you can see from the code, `LocalDate` has a method for subtracting 10 days (or any other number of days).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding query parameter as a string:

```
st.setString(1, str);
```

Consider binding it as Date:

```
st.setDate(1, new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").parse(str));
```

ofcourse use your desired [date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You can also do the conversion in database leaving java code intact but modifying your query:

```
select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date=STR_TO_DATE(?, "%M %d %Y");
```

Additionaly consider comparing dates to ranges (don't use "=", use ">" instead)

Comment: Could you write query for 10days back records

Comment: select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)

Comment: or if you mean 10 days from date typed in tf5:select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(?, "%M %d %Y"), INTERVAL 10 DAY); Remember to use proper format in STR_TO_DATE function (read more here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Comment: `Date` is probably better than `String`, but (1) the `Date` classes are poorly designed and long outdated (2) your format pattern string is definitely wrong (3) I think you need `java.sql.Date` if you insist on `Date`, but the notoriously troublesome and equally outdated `SimpleDateFormat` parses into `java.util.Date`.

Comment: In date column database I have 2019-05-28,2019-05-25,2019-05-24.I am filling typing in t5 2019-05-28.Getting error "No record found".Following is code after changes       String str = tf5.getText();
                   Connection con=DB.getConnection();
                  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date=?");
                 
                 
                  st.setString(1, str);
                  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

Comment: //following is for display data in table   pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('"+str+"', \"%Y %m %d\"), INTERVAL 04 DAY);");
               ResultSet rs1 = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: I have done some changes again in code for textbox(t5) .I wrote the following code.  String str = tf5.getText();
                   Connection con=DB.getConnection();
                 PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date=?");
                  st.setString(1, str);
                  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(); and to featch data into table following  pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from issuedevices where Issue_Date = '" + str + "'- INTERVAL '04' DAY"); .I am typing in textbox(t5) 2019-05-28.Its giving  record 2019-05-28   table.

Comment: Actually now my code is first checking in database testbox typed value(2019-05-28). Because it is in database so it is giving me record of 2019-05-24 in table. How write code so that it directly give 04 days back values after typing date value in textbox. Like after typing 2019-06-04(this value is not in table) get record of 2019-06-01(this is in table)

Comment: @rama totally unclear what you're asking and code in comments is unreadable. If you have a date string, create a proper Java `LocalDate` object first, this can be used to do operations on it. But, either open a new question if it is different from the current or edit your current question.

Comment: I have solve this question .Thanks everyone for your help.